# New names in truth trees for predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I want to know when I have to introduce a new name when constructing a truth tree for predicate logic. For example:

Determine whether this is valid or not using a truth tree.

($\exists$xPx & $\exists$xQx) $\models$ $\exists$x(Px & Qx)

Do I simplify the first part as Pa | Qa OR Pa | Qb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you think about this logically:

$\exists x \ P(x) \land \exists x \ Q(x)$ says that there is something that is a $P$, and that there is something that is a $Q$.  Can we assume that is the same thing?  Of course not! For example, suppose we are talking about numbers, and $P$ is 'Even', and $Q$ is 'Odd'.  So, if you use $a$ to denote 'some object that has property $P$', then you will need to use a different constant $b$ to denote 'some object that has property $Q$'.

And by the way, just because we use different constants $a$ and $b$ does not mean that $a$ and $b$ denote different objects; they can be different labels for the same object. That is, it can turn out later that $a = b$.  But by using $a$ and $b$ we leave it open as to whether 'the thing with property $P$' is the same 'thing with property $Q$' or not. And that is exactly what we want for the truth-tree method, since in the truth tree method we are trying to systematically explore *all* the possible ways to satisfy some set of sentences. Whereas if you set $P(a) \land Q(a)$ in order to satisfy $\exists x \ P(x) \land \exists x \ Q(x)$, you will have found a way to satisfy that statement, but you do *not* explore *all* possible ways to satisfy that statement.

Long story short: *Anytime* you drop an existential, you need to introduce a new constant!

Answer (score 1):

A new name must be used when "unpacking" an existential quantifier and a negated universal quantifier.

From $\exists x  Px$ to $Pa$, the parameter $a$ must be "new".

The same for de derivation of $\lnot Pa$ from $\lnot \forall x Pa$.

---

In your example, if we start with the prermise: $∃xPx \land ∃xQx$, we have to apply the $\land$-rule in order to derive: $∃xPx$ and $∃xQx$.

In the next steps, using the $∃$-rule, we have to introduce two new names to get: $Pa$ and $Qb$.